# Output voltage error

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, adc, buffer, drift

[image]

This is an external protection circuit for an analog to digital converter. I have modelled the resistive sensor as a voltage divider.

I have used pull down resistor R14 to avoid floating input then I have used a voltage follower. After that I have used voltage divider (R15-R16) to scale the input voltage range from (0-10V) to (0-5V,) after the second stage buffer I am using a RC low pass filter and I am using a schottky diode as a positive voltage clipper for over voltage protection.

I am using R18 to model the high input impedance of analog to digital converter.

The issue that I am facing is that when the sensor gives a voltage of 4 volts, the divider makes it 2V but at final_adc_in I am getting a voltage of 2.1 V.  I am getting a voltage drift for every sensor input voltage.

Any suggestion for reducing this voltage drift to minimum?

Comment: This is all useless design.. Start with all In Out specs

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 i have added pull down to avoid floating input and voltage divider for voltage scaling and RC for filtering ,the adc ic is Ads1115 , what is the mistake?

Comment: never ask a question without stating all the design In to Out specs for everything including tolerance acceptance error limits

Comment: basically i am designing this circuit for for ADC ic ADS1115

Comment: So what? You have too many assumptions and a tolerance stackup with useless stages

Comment: i want to sense analog voltage between (0-10V) but Ic can only take Voltage between 0-5 that's i have added a voltage divider circuit and i have added pull down to avoid floating input and RC circuit for noise Filter are this too many assumption ?

Comment: @powermachines:  This is not drift.  It is "error." A drift would change with time or temperature.

Comment: sorry @JRE,Removing D7 will minimize the error

Comment: You cannot be at all serious about using an AD549 - in Farnell they cost £35 each. You are going about this all wrong. You do need to state your specifications or you won't get a decent answer. The devil is in the absolute detail and you have provided none. At the very minimum you should state what voltage range from your input device you want to work with and what power supplies you have available. What you have at the moment is a pig's ear that costs at least £70 per channel. Sort this out.

Comment: Don’t ask another question until you list all input output requirement specs and tolerances with sources of errors (all) or concerns, budget etc

Comment: sorry for asking such incomplete question

Comment: @powermachines you have accepted an answer and that closes down the question and, others coming along later might think the answer has given you acceptable advice. The answer does give good advice but it's not the "full solution" someone might interpret it as. I have no idea why you haven't pursued this problem until all the bugs were removed but, if you think changing the diode will solve the problems, please  think again. This site is a showcase for good questions and answers and, unfortunately this isn't one of them. I would advise you to take action to fix this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Remove D7, and I think the output situation will improve.

The [1N5817](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds23001.pdf) has a reverse leakage current of up to 1 mA.  That combined with resistor R17 lets the 5V rail pull the output away from its intended value.

D7 acts like a resistor and forms a voltage divider with R17.  The result is somewhere between the 5V rail and the output voltage from U2.

The 1N5817 is more for high current applications.

You'll need to find a replacement for D7 with a far lower reverse leakage current.

---

The [ADS1115](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ADS1114) can only tolerate 5.3V on its analog input when operating on 5.3.

You will need a diode with a low foward voltage (less than 0.3V) to really protect the ADS1115.  You will need a diode with a very small reverse leakage current to minimize the error in your protection circuit.

Comment: thanks for help@JRE

Comment: Very likely R17 is enough protection to keep the ADC input pin going more than 0.3 V above the supply.

Comment: The datasheet for the ADS1115 recommends using a series resistor and a schottky diode if the input can exceed 5.3V.

Comment: @JRE i didn't understood the relation of reverse leakage current with diode resistance ,like if  i take diode of less reverse leakage current  diode resistance will more right?

Comment: Right.  A diode with a smaller leakage current will act like a larger resistor and disturb your ADC input less.

Comment: thanks for help@JRE